# PHP 5.5, NGINX and Memcached - 502 Error

Tags: nginx, memcached, php-5.5

I'm having a problem with Memcached pools. I will try to add all the context of the error to see if you guys can help me with this.

**Context:**

- PHP 5.5.17 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Sep 24 2014 20:38:04)
- php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.fc17.remi.5.5.x86_64
- nginx version:
  nginx/1.0.15

**My problem:**

I am creating a connection with memcached and saving a several keys, just in one server first, something like this:

```
$_memcache = new Memcache;
$_memcache->addServer("127.0.0.1", "11211", true, 50, 3600, 45);
```

So, let suppose that I add several keys, in that server and I can get those without problem, I actually can, when I see my site and my code is calling to get the keys, it's getting it.

Now the problem, let say with those keys already saved and working without problem, I added another memcached server to the pool, this way:

```
$_memcache = new Memcache;
$_memcache->addServer("10.0.0.2", "11211", true, 50, 3600, 45);
$_memcache->addServer("10.0.0.3", "11211", true, 50, 3600, 45);
```

But before I refreshed the site to run my code and get the keys that I have storage in the first server I stopped the memcached in that server number 1 (10.0.0.2), after that I refreshed my site and then I received a 502 error (Bad Gateway)

The error that I am seeing in the log of NGINX is:

*[error] 9364#0: *329504 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: XX.XX.XXX.XXX, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fastcgi/sock:", host: "www.myhost.com"*

So, why I am getting that error. The only theory that I have is that for some reason because the connections is persistent is not closing properly when I stop the memcached server, but that only happens when I have a pool of X > 1 servers. If I use just that one and stopped I won't see the error.

There is any way that PHP 5.5 has a bug with the fastcgi socket that I don't know.

**NOTE:** This problem that I am having wasn't happening on previous PHP version 5.3, after changing the version is this is happening.

**NOTE:** When I don't use persistent connection seems to work, but this site has a huge traffic and it won't handle the amount of connections open, I tested this in dev environment.

Any help or any suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you run the script from CLI? This should make the debugging easier. Especially if it's some sort of segfault.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @lxg, for some reason I didn't think to do something like that, the error that I am receiving from that test that I did is: PHP Notice: "MemcachePool::get(): Server 10.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Read failed (socket was unexpectedly closed) (0)", that error make sense but how can I over pass this in NGINX?

Comment: 1. A PHP notice is usually a sign of sloppy programming. Usually if you expect something to be there, but isn't. Before retrieving values from a Memcached server, you should check if it's available at all. 2. I think that you need to analyze more to find the actual cause of the problem. Because the fact that the server is not available is just a *symptom* of the underlying problem.

Comment: Well, what I meant is that the PHP Notice at least make sense because it match what I see in NGINX, that the socket closed unexpectedly, but of course that was intentional, what I don't understand is why this is making NGINX throwing 502 errors?

Comment: A 502 means that the “upstream” (i.e. PHP-FPM) died unexpectedly – which it does indeed. See also http://www.nginxtips.com/502-bad-gateway-using-nginx/

Comment: Yea, I am using PHP-CGI, but your example is valid, it's dying the thing is that I don't know where or why is doing that.